# Onclick event works only one time

Tags: javascript, cordova

I use this code to display Ads on Cordova mobile app:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  admob.interstitial.load({
    id: {
      // replace with your ad unit IDs
      android: 'ca-app-pub-1266469958489664/1154250177',
      ios: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/zzz',
    },
  })
}, false)

document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.load', () => {
  // handle event
   document.getElementById('showAd').onclick = function() {
      admob.interstitial.show()
    }

},)
```

the problem is that the Ad is displayed just one time. after that the button does not show any ad.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prepare ads before calling add this function

```
  admob.interstitial.prepare()
```

like this when you close interstitial you prepare a new interstitial :

```
document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
  console.log(event)

  admob.interstitial.prepare()
})
```